# Powershell: Using WhatIf when passing an array to a function

Tags: powershell

I have a function that finds some XML elements, then passes these to another function to be manipulated. As calling the outer function is going result in XML data being altered, I've used the `Set` verb when naming it. Good practice is to use `WhatIf` with functions that alter data.

The problem I have is that I'm passing an array of XML elements to `Set-InlineCssStyle` and I want the output of `ShouldProcess` to reflect each one of the items.

I think the code I've come up with smells!

```
...
if ($WhatIfPreference)
{
    $elements.ForEach({
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($_.Name, 'Set-InlineCssStyle')){}
    })
}
else
{
    Set-InlineCssStyle -Elements $elements -Style $Style
}
...
```

What is the best way to deal with using `WhatIf` when passing an array to a function?

Comment: The best way would be to implement `ShouldProcess` support in `Set-InlineCssStyle` and then pass the common parameters to it inside the calling function

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the response. Set-InlineCssStyle is a private function and will not be exported. I have a number of public functions that will call `Set-InlineCssStyle`. I wanted to implment `ShouldProcess` in each of these functions so that the user will know what XML elements will be afftected.

I'm considering moving the call to `Set-InlineCssstyle` into the scriptblock for `ShouldProcess` and excepting multiple calls to it. This is a bit inefficient, but would not have a major impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate checks. `ShouldProcess(Target,Action)` only returns true (which would run the if-true-block) if you didn't use `-WhatIf` or if you used `-Confirm` and answered yes for that item. So the whole `if($WhatIfPreference)`-part is not needed. Try:

```
function TestWhatIf {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $elements
    )

    Process {   
        $elements.ForEach({
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($_.Name, 'Hello')){
                "Hello $($_.Name)"
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Output:

```
#WhatIf
>Get-ChildItem | TestWhatIf -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Hello" on target ".dnx".
What if: Performing the operation "Hello" on target ".nuget".
What if: Performing the operation "Hello" on target ".vscode".
What if: Performing the operation "Hello" on target "3D Objects".
What if: Performing the operation "Hello" on target "Base".
....

#Without WhatIf
>Get-ChildItem | TestWhatIf
Hello .dnx
Hello .nuget
Hello .vscode
Hello 3D Objects
Hello Base
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. The code is structured that way as I want to call `Set-InlineCssStyle` only once passing in an array. However, I want to output a line for each item in the array.

Comment: Okay. I don't see any better way of achieving that compared to what you have, except moving it inside the `Set-InlineCssStyle` where it should be (since that's the reusable cmdlet that actually does the work).

Comment: I think you and @Mathias are right. So I've moved the `ShouldProcess` into `Set-InlineCssstyle`. This means passing `-WhatIf` from the calling script, through each of the public functions and finally to `Set-InlineCssstyle`. In order to do this I've added `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]` to each of the public functions. However, ScritpAnalyzer complains that it's not used in the each of the public functions. So, I've surpressed this warning for each of them. This seems a better solution.